# c++ random number with a given probability array

Tags: c++, distribution, probability, random

I have an array of probability for some actions identified by array index(e.g. like Boltzmann distribution )

```
for(int i=0;i<N_ACTIONS;i++)
        {
            p[i]=exp(q_tab[state()][i]/T);

            if(isnan(p[i]))
            {
                p[i]=0;
            }

        }
        long double s=p.sum();
        for(int i=0;i<N_ACTIONS;i++)   
        {
            p[i]=p[i]/s; 
        }
```

I have to choice a random number i between 0 and N_ACTIONS-1 with probability p[i]; I made this but doesn't seem working well:

```
int ChoiceFromDist(valarray<long double> p)
{
    int                   index=0;
    valarray<long double> cumulativa(p.size());

    cumulativa[0]=p[0];

    for(int i=1; i < p.size(); i++)
        cumulativa[i]  =  cumulativa[i-1]+p[i];

    long double num= ( (long double)rand()/(long double)RAND_MAX ); 

    while(index<p.size() && cumulativa[index]<num )
        index++;
    return index;
}
```

caller:

```
srand(time(0));
act=ChoiceFromDist(p);
```

It seems to choice always the same number (from 0 to 2 it choices 2) ....Do you see  something wrong or the error coulbe in another code point?
Thanks

Comment: Please show us the contents of `p` from a test where `ChoiceFromDist` didn't work as it should.

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but you might want to read about the new [pseudo-random facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that came with the new C++11 standard.

Comment: Check and tell us the numbers of p.size() and num.

Comment: Are you calling srand(time(0)) before every call to ChoiceFromDist()? If so, then you are going to get the same result for every call that occurs during the same clock second and won't get a different result until the second hand ticks on the clock. You should call srand(time(0)) from main() and not call it again after that.

Comment: nono...the srand(Tim(0)) is called just one time..I write it so that you see I don't forget it :)

Comment: p_0:37.6516 sum: 1455.46 ratio: p_0/sum:0.0258692 
p_1:0.142752 sum: 1455.46 ratio: p_1/sum:9.80802e-05 
p_2:1417.67 sum: 1455.46 ratio: p_2/sum:0.974033

it could be right (p_ is a sum of values)...but I have doubs on the algorithm correctness written...anyone can tell me if it seems to be right?